# Apache ModRewrite pattern not stored

Tags: regex, bash, mod-rewrite, lamp

I can't figure out why the below doesn't work

```
RewriteCond ${foobar:test:$1} ^
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /check.php?url=$1 [L]
```

`foobar` is a program (simple bash script) and from within it I am writing to file to see what the input is. `check.php` is a simple php script which displays the contents of `GET`. Here is what I get when I pass the regular expression (`$1`) to both the shell script and the php script:

```
url                          check.php             foobar

www.example.com/index.html   index.html            test:
www.example.com/index.php    index.php             test:
www.example.com/test.html    test.html             test:
```

basically, the pattern is recognized within the RewriteRule, but not the parameter to foobar.

Note: there is nothing wrong with the shell script. If instead I call it like so `${foobar:test:abc123}` the output is "`test:abc123`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view:

```
RewriteCond ${foobar:test:$1} ^
```

the first **`$1`** is a non-sense because **`$1`** should refer to a previous expression, like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /check.php?url=$1 [L]
```

So I don't get how this could work, and if something works, it's... strange.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Maybe something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${foobar:test:$1} [R,L,NC]
```

Could work.